# EditText in async class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-edittext

I'm trying to show some text that I got from a link in an EditText inside async onPostExecute methode 
here is my code I send a GET request to get the JSON array then I convert it into a string to show it in an EditText the problem that it stops (with exception) when I try to set text to Edit text  :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyPage extends Activity {
  Tools tools = new Tools() ; 
  String str ="" ; 
  //TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1) ; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_page);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String name = extras.getString("name");
            String pass = extras.getString("pass");
            String url = "http://example.com/Andoid/getdata.php?"
                    + "name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass;
            GetData gd = new GetData() ; 

            gd.execute(url) ; 
            //txt.setText(str) ; 
        }
    }

    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            JSONArray jsonArry = null;
            String data = null;
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // HttpClient
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array

            if (httpEntity != null) {
                try {
                    String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    jsonArry = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                data = tools.JsonGetData(jsonArry);

            }
            return data;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        EditText edttxt = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3) ; 
        edttxt.setText(result ,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE) ; 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        str = result ; 
    }



    }
```

I debugged the app and it stop with an exception on this line  :

```
edttxt.setText(result) ;
```

I don't know why and how to solve it ?

Here is the log history from LogCat :

```
12-18 02:11:44.780: I/dalvikvm(4223): Debugger is active
12-18 02:11:44.810: I/System.out(4223): Debugger has connected
12-18 02:11:44.810: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.020: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.230: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.440: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.650: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.860: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.070: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.280: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.490: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.700: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.910: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:47.120: I/System.out(4223): debugger has settled (1430)
12-18 02:11:47.220: I/PGA(4223): New SOCKET connection: com.example.socialnetcit (pid 4223, tid 4223)
12-18 02:12:48.650: I/Choreographer(4223): Skipped 1816 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 02:19:47.150: W/ActivityThread(4303): Application com.example.socialnetcit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-18 02:19:47.160: I/System.out(4303): Sending WAIT chunk
12-18 02:19:47.280: I/dalvikvm(4303): Debugger is active
12-18 02:19:47.370: I/System.out(4303): Debugger has connected
12-18 02:19:47.370: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:47.580: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:47.790: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.000: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.210: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.420: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.630: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.840: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:49.050: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:49.260: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:49.470: I/System.out(4303): debugger has settled (1420)
12-18 02:19:49.610: I/PGA(4303): New SOCKET connection: com.example.socialnetcit (pid 4303, tid 4303)
12-18 02:20:16.200: D/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=13: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-18 02:20:18.390: D/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=13: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-18 02:20:18.390: I/Choreographer(4303): Skipped 669 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 02:21:24.760: D/AndroidRuntime(4303): Shutting down VM
12-18 02:21:24.760: W/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d79b20)
12-18 02:21:24.760: D/AndroidRuntime(4303): procName from cmdline: com.example.socialnetcit
12-18 02:21:24.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.socialnetcit
12-18 02:21:24.760: D/AndroidRuntime(4303): file written successfully with content: com.example.socialnetcit StringBuffer : ;com.example.socialnetcit
12-18 02:21:24.760: W/FileUtils(4303): Failed to chmod(/data/data/.tmp/.crashed_app): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
12-18 02:21:24.780: I/Process(4303): Sending signal. PID: 4303 SIG: 9
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): Process: com.example.socialnetcit, PID: 4303
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.example.socialnetcit.MyPage$GetData.onPostExecute(MyPage.java:84)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.example.socialnetcit.MyPage$GetData.onPostExecute(MyPage.java:1)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have modified textedit3 to an existed TextEdit   but I still have the problem ith new exceptions :

```
12-18 02:11:44.780: I/dalvikvm(4223): Debugger is active
12-18 02:11:44.810: I/System.out(4223): Debugger has connected
12-18 02:11:44.810: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.020: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.230: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.440: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.650: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:45.860: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.070: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.280: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.490: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.700: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:46.910: I/System.out(4223): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:11:47.120: I/System.out(4223): debugger has settled (1430)
12-18 02:11:47.220: I/PGA(4223): New SOCKET connection: com.example.socialnetcit (pid 4223, tid 4223)
12-18 02:12:48.650: I/Choreographer(4223): Skipped 1816 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 02:19:47.150: W/ActivityThread(4303): Application com.example.socialnetcit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-18 02:19:47.160: I/System.out(4303): Sending WAIT chunk
12-18 02:19:47.280: I/dalvikvm(4303): Debugger is active
12-18 02:19:47.370: I/System.out(4303): Debugger has connected
12-18 02:19:47.370: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:47.580: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:47.790: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.000: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.210: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.420: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.630: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:48.840: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:49.050: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:49.260: I/System.out(4303): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:19:49.470: I/System.out(4303): debugger has settled (1420)
12-18 02:19:49.610: I/PGA(4303): New SOCKET connection: com.example.socialnetcit (pid 4303, tid 4303)
12-18 02:20:16.200: D/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=13: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-18 02:20:18.390: D/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=13: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-18 02:20:18.390: I/Choreographer(4303): Skipped 669 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 02:21:24.760: D/AndroidRuntime(4303): Shutting down VM
12-18 02:21:24.760: W/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d79b20)
12-18 02:21:24.760: D/AndroidRuntime(4303): procName from cmdline: com.example.socialnetcit
12-18 02:21:24.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.socialnetcit
12-18 02:21:24.760: D/AndroidRuntime(4303): file written successfully with content: com.example.socialnetcit StringBuffer : ;com.example.socialnetcit
12-18 02:21:24.760: W/FileUtils(4303): Failed to chmod(/data/data/.tmp/.crashed_app): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
12-18 02:21:24.780: I/Process(4303): Sending signal. PID: 4303 SIG: 9
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): Process: com.example.socialnetcit, PID: 4303
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.example.socialnetcit.MyPage$GetData.onPostExecute(MyPage.java:84)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.example.socialnetcit.MyPage$GetData.onPostExecute(MyPage.java:1)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
12-18 02:21:24.780: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 02:41:20.480: W/ActivityThread(4502): Application com.example.socialnetcit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-18 02:41:20.490: I/System.out(4502): Sending WAIT chunk
12-18 02:41:23.690: I/dalvikvm(4502): Debugger is active
12-18 02:41:23.850: I/System.out(4502): Debugger has connected
12-18 02:41:23.850: I/System.out(4502): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:41:24.060: I/System.out(4502): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:41:24.270: I/System.out(4502): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:41:24.480: I/System.out(4502): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:41:24.690: I/System.out(4502): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:41:24.900: I/System.out(4502): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-18 02:41:25.110: I/System.out(4502): debugger has settled (1310)
12-18 02:41:25.250: I/PGA(4502): New SOCKET connection: com.example.socialnetcit (pid 4502, tid 4502)
```

Comment: Could you please post the exception information?

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash so we know what the exception is. Or look at it and try to see what it means.

Comment: `NullPointerException`. Looks like `editText3` is not in `activity_my_page.xml`. You might also want to see [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) and [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I can't read that in a comment. If you have a different problem then you need to post a new question. And nothing you just put in the comment would really help to solve the issue, anyway. We **need** the exception